# SOLVED - Issues installing Steam

Tags: steam

So I'm trying to install Steam. I've tried multiple ways.

First I tried via AppCenter, but that's the Flatpak version where Proton doesn't work above a certain version. The version I need to play what I want to play is not working at all with the Flatpak version.

I tried downloading the .deb from Steams Website. Crashes immediately after launching. No window pops up or anything, it just flashes on the dock.

Tried `sudo apt install steam-installer`. Crashes after updating and then refuses to start.

Tried `sudo apt install steam`. Same as above.

When I try launching Steam from the terminal, this is what my terminal says:

```
rqi@MS759665d3526a:~$ steam
Running Steam on elementary 6 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/rqi/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
[2021-09-30 18:10:27] Startup - updater built Sep 17 2021 04:27:28
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  44
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-09-30 18:10:27] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2021-09-30 18:10:27] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2021-09-30 18:10:27] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2021-09-30 18:10:27] Checking for update on startup
[2021-09-30 18:10:27] Checking for available updates...
[2021-09-30 18:10:27] Downloading manifest: http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2021-09-30 18:10:28] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1631912732, installed version 1631912732, existing pending version 0
[2021-09-30 18:10:28] Nothing to do
[2021-09-30 18:10:28] Verifying installation...
[2021-09-30 18:10:28] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-09-30 18:10:28] Verification complete
rqi@MS759665d3526a:~$
```

After that Steam disappears from Dock, never to be seen again.

Never had an issue while using eOS 5.1, so I really don't understand why it refuses to work now. I have i386 enabled, so that's not the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For some reason, installing "nvidia-driver-460-server" worked, although I already had drivers installed.

Comment: Glad you could solve the issue. As this is a Q&A site rather than a forum, could you change your edit into an Answer, then mark it as accepted?